# How can populate a jquery generated select with the values 1-52

Tags: jquery, html

I am using jquery to add a select field after a radio button is changed. The code looks like this:

```
$("<label>For: </label><select><option value='1'>1</option>"+
                            "<option value='2'>2</option>"+
                            "<option value='3'>3</option>"+
                            "<option value='4'>4</option>"+
                            "<option value='5'>5</option>"+
                            "<option value='6'>6</option>"+
                            "<option value='7'>7</option>"+
                            "<option value='8'>8</option>"+
                            "<option value='9'>9</option>"+
                            "<option value='10'>10</option>"+
                            "<option value='11'>11</option>"+
                            "<option value='12'>12</option>"+
                            "</select><label>Weeks</label>")
.attr("id", "duration")
.attr("name", "duration")
.attr("class", "duration")
.appendTo("#durationVal");
```

I tried using an array, but this just populated the select with all elements of the array in in field. I have also tried using a for loop to this, but this does nothing at all. The idea is when a use click on a radio button for a recurring job, the next set of radio's appear to let the use choose a monthly or weekly recurrence. This then brings up the final select i want as a select that allows for 26 weeks or 6 months depending on the radio button selected.
How can I do this so I don't have to add each option manually? The above works, but it ugly and way too much typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get the jquery code to work as I needed, so I wrote to selects into my html using a php loop to populate them like this:

```
  <td id="selmn_td"><label>Times: </label>
    <select name="selectMN" id="selectorMN" ><?PHP 
                                            for ($i = 1;$i<13;$i++)
                                             echo "<option value=" . $i . ">" .$i . "</option>";
                                            ?>
    </select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="selwk_td"><label>Times: </label>
    <select name="selectWK" id="selector" style="visibility:hidden" ><?PHP 
                                                                for ($i = 1;$i<53;$i++)
                                                                 echo "<option value=" . $i . ">" .$i . "</option>";
                                                                ?>
    </select><label id="weeks"></label><label id="months"></label></td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td id="weekdays" colspan="2">
        <input type="checkbox" name="weekdays[]" value="Monday" id="weekdays_0" />Mon</label><label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="weekdays[]" value="Tuesday" id="weekdays_1" />Tues</label><label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="weekdays[]" value="Wednesday" id="weekdays_2" />Wed</label><label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="weekdays[]" value="Thursday" id="weekdays_3" />Thu</label><label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="weekdays[]" value="Friday" id="weekdays_4" />Fri</label><label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="weekdays[]" value="Saturday" id="weekdays_5" />Sat</label><label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="weekdays[]" value="Sunday" id="weekdays_6" />Sun</label>
  </td>
```

I then used the following jquery to show and hide the input fields:

```
        $('#RadioGroup1_0').change(function()
        {
            document.getElementById('radio_duration_td').style.visibility="visible";
            document.getElementById('selwk_td').style.visibility="visible";
            document.getElementById('selector').style.visibility="visible";
            document.getElementById('weekdays').style.visibility="visible";

        $('#RadioGroup1_1').change(function()
        {
            document.getElementById('radio_duration_td').style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById('selwk_td').style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById('selector').style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById('weekdays').style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById('selmn_td').style.visibility="hidden";
        }
        );  

        $('#radio_duration_1').change(function()
        {
            document.getElementById('weeks').style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById('weekdays').style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById('selmn_td').style.visibility="visible";
            document.getElementById('selector').style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById('selwk_td').style.visibility="hidden";
            //document.getElementById('selwk_td').style.visibility="visible";
            //document.getElementById('selector').style.visibility="visible";
        }
        );                              
        $('#radio_duration_2').change(function()
        {
            document.getElementById('weekdays').style.visibility="visible";
            document.getElementById('selector').style.visibility="visible";
            document.getElementById('selwk_td').style.visibility="visible";
            document.getElementById('selmn_td').style.visibility="hidden";
            //document.getElementById('months').style.visibility="hidden";
        }
```

This is not ideal, but when deadlines are pushed you have to go with what works. Suggestions on this would still be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

At the moment you are creating a single option select box every time you go through the loop, you want to create the options not the select in the loop

```
var select = $("<select></select>");
for (i=1;i<53;i++)
{
   select.append( $('<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>') );
}
$("#WhateverElement").append(select);
```

And since you are start the loop at 1 you should use either `i<53` or `i<=52` so that you get the full 52 values

Also you have

```
.attr("id", "durationW")
.attr("class", "duration")
.appendTo("#durationVal");
```

right after the for loop block which is invalid, has no meaning, and should be throwing some kind of error as its not attached to any object.